# Is there a self-publishing service that can publish workbooks and flash drives?

Tags: self-publishing, printing

There are various self-publishing services, like Amazon Publishing, B&N Press, Lulu, etc.

I need a self-publishing service that can not only handle printing a traditional hardback book, but also print workbooks and distribute flash-drives (or DVDs) with data on them for customers.

When searching for such a service, what options do I need to look for in page quality to know that it fits a workbook? Is here certain kinds of binding, weight, and texture of paper used for this? Or is it exactly the same as the cheaper paperback options?

Comment: Do you really have to ship flash drives or DVDs? Many people these days don't have DVD players or even laptop computers with a USB Type A port for a conventional flash drive. Wouldn't it be simpler to provide a download of electronic content? (An alternative would be to allow people to write to you and request a DVD/flash drive: maybe include a cut-out form in the book.)

Answer (score 2):

Every common self-publishing service will publish workbooks. The technical aspect of the publishing process is the same for workbooks, novels, and other types of book. The only limitation for all books is that ebooks don't work well with full page illustrations and tables, but self-published printed books are all the same from their technical side.

There is no self-publishing service that I am aware of that publishes bundles of books and other media such as DVDs or flash drives. You will probably have to publish that yourself and use both a book-publishing service and a service that creates DVDs or flash drives and combine the bundles yourself when you mail them.

Comment: Especially with the more basic publishers, there may be limits around size and format of books and around illustrations, making them more suitable for novels etc, but the OP doesn't specify what size or style of workbook they want.